# Parsing a Large text file in Python using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

How to store a text data starting from a certain word and ending with a certain word in a large text file (using python and regex).

Here is a part of text file:

```
X_FUNCTION = linear
TITLE =
netlist_run
Vnet04  YUNITS = volts
+  0.000000000000000E+00 -4.000000000000000E-01  3.636363636363636E-02 -4.000000000000000E-01
+  7.272727272727272E-02 -4.000000000000000E-01  1.090909090909091E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01
+  1.454545454545454E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01  1.818181818181818E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01
+  2.181818181818182E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01  2.545454545454546E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01
+  2.909090909090910E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01  3.272727272727273E-01 -4.000000000000000E-01
Vnet05  YUNITS = volts
+  0.000000000000000E+00  3.000000000000000E+00  3.636363636363636E-02  3.000000000000000E+00
+  7.272727272727272E-02  3.000000000000000E+00  1.090909090909091E-01  3.000000000000000E+00
+  1.454545454545454E-01  3.000000000000000E+00  1.818181818181818E-01  3.000000000000000E+00
+  2.181818181818182E-01  3.000000000000000E+00  2.545454545454546E-01  3.000000000000000E+00
+  2.909090909090910E-01  3.000000000000000E+00  3.272727272727273E-01  3.000000000000000E+00
vbs_i  YUNITS = amps
+  0.000000000000000E+00  3.881535006369462E-12  3.636363636363636E-02  3.958355883215995E-12
+  7.272727272727272E-02  4.155732392087960E-12  1.090909090909091E-01  4.661608907762973E-12
+  1.454545454545454E-01  5.953136322408749E-12  1.818181818181818E-01  9.230381781895836E-12
+  2.181818181818182E-01  1.746801289794467E-11  2.545454545454546E-01  3.787865538450135E-11
+  2.909090909090910E-01  8.739483655864867E-11  3.272727272727273E-01  2.040272699537106E-10
```

I want to start saving the data starting from line `Vnet04  YUNITS = volts` till just before the starting of line `Vnet05  YUNITS = volts` in a object let say `a`. and then again I want to save data starting from line `Vnet05  YUNITS = volts` till just before the starting of line `vbs_i  YUNITS = amps` in a object `b`

As my text file is over 1000k lines. I want to parse it only once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wish your comment can be included as a template reply to assist new users.

Comment: You want to do this only through a `regex`? I think there are other ways too which a regular expression is not needed, but you have to iterate through the file's liens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

ins = open( "test.txt", "r" )
array = []
array2 = []
i = 0
for line in ins:
    if ((re.match('Vnet05 YUNITS = volts) or re.match('vbs_i YUNITS = amps')) and (i != 0 ):
        array.append(array2)
        i += 1
        array2 = []
        array2.append( line )
    elif line.startswith('+') :
        i += 1
        array2.append(line)

array.append(array2)
for line in array:
    print("Object :")
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you all of you. Thanks a lot Upasanaa :)

Comment: Dear Upasanaa, could you please help me ? I want to make little change in above code. I want to grab only the lines "Vnet05  YUNITS = volts" and "vbs_i  YUNITS = amps" and data followed by these lines. How should I proceed ? thanks.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. But in this case its also storing the contents of each line that is followed by "+" symbol. That means the content after the line "Vnet04  YUNITS = volts" and before the line "Vnet05  YUNITS = volts". I do not want all the lines appearing before the line "Vnet05  YUNITS = volts". Thanks !

Comment: since here we have used for loop, we are parsing each line.

Comment: Hello Upasanaa, Could you please help me to write above script without using if-else condition ? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not that good at Python, so can't tell you about any other way of writing this script. But you may use DOTALL flag for modifying your regular expression and then proceeding accordingly. Better to learn Python yourself, instead of repeatedly asking someone to help you in your work :)

Answer (score 0):

1) write a regexp match for your "start" and "stop" lines

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#examples
As the commenters have mentioned you may not need a regexp to do this

2) read the line in line by line and compare with the start and stop lines, use this to set a state variable true or false

3) if the state variable is true use append to add the line to an array

at the end of the file you should have the lines of interest in an array